# Three.js antialiasing, box geometry still very unsharp

Tags: three.js, antialiasing

im trying to create a simple 3d game with boxgeometries in three.js.
Everything works good but im not getting sharp edges on those boxes, no matter on mobile browser (safari) or on chrome on my macbook. See the screenshot below.
[image: Blurry Edges on Meshes]

What i tried so far: set antialias on renderer to true (helps but still no straight lines from rotated cubes), set renderer pixel ratio (touch click intersects dont work then, and still pixelated lines.) Also tried the FXAA shader but result was not better.
Using perspective camera, Boxgeometry with Basic Material.

My Question is, is it with three.js even possible to have sharp edges on those cubes ? especially when they are pretty small (like 30 equal sized on mobile screen).

Using three.js version 87, chrome 68, newest mobile safari.

Update: This is my renderer settings:

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
alpha: true,
antialias: true
   });
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
 renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio); // doesnt do the trick and messes up the threex domevent touch inputs
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);


  canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
  window.onresize = resizeCanvas;
  resizeCanvas();

  function resizeCanvas() {
    canvas.style.width = '100%';
    canvas.style.height = '100%';

canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth;
canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight;

camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  }
```

in my css i only have     canvas { height: 100%; width: 100%; }

update2: demo link here https://jsfiddle.net/roxanfc4/11/

Comment: Can you share a demo? Do the official three.js examples looks sharp on your device? It's certainly possible to get clean edges in three.js, but hard to guess why it's not working in your case without some information about your specific scene.

Comment: It sort of looks like the anti-aliasing is taking place, but then your canvas is scaled up through CSS. Do you happen to have any CSS rules like `transform: scale(2.0);` or something like that applied to your canvas, div, page, etc?

Answer (score 7):

Somehow this snippet did the trick and the edges are clearly softer now:

```
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio * 1.5);
```

Comment: i'm pretty sure this is kind of a hack that relies antialiasing to browser rather than three.js, but it saved my day and i don't have to include/write antialiasing shaders. i hope this hack will keep on working across devices

Comment: also, i think that the jagged line problem occurs mainly on devices with a device pixel ratio of 1. perhaps it would be better to do something like `if(window.devicePixelRatio<2){ renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio * 2); }`, to make sure that the resulting pixel ratio is not too high? anyways i have found this thread https://discourse.threejs.org/t/prevent-canvas-graining/11621/4 but you it shed no additional light on the problem

Comment: Why `* 1.5`? Just using `renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio)` did the trick just fine for me!

Answer (score 0):

Just `renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio)` should be fine. I dont think you need the x 1.5 part. [Reference](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/render-looks-blurry-and-pixelated-even-with-antialias-true-why/12381/2)